# Canvas appears over content

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas, z-index

Even though `canvas` element is placed before webpage content it appears on top.

```
<canvas id="cnv"></canvas>
<div id="content">
    blah blah
    <p>
         blahs
    </p>
</div>
```

One solution would be to set `z-index` to -1 for canvas but that would stop `mousemove` from being triggered.

Why is the canvas on top? How can I place it behind content while still being able to trigger mousemove?

http://jsfiddle.net/YUx82/

NOTE: The only CSS I am allowed to change is the one for the canvas.
Another solution would be setting z-index to -1 and then somehow passing the mousemove from the document to the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
$("#cnv").on("transferMouseCoordinates", function(e, x, y){
  // voila!
});

$(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
  // use e.pageX and e.pageY to get mouse position
  $("#cnv").trigger("transferMouseCoordinates", e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
```

Comment: Also note that Fixed is not safe to use on mobile devices, use absolute instead.

Comment: i added trigger to show you the use of events but you could just call the function directly without the use of events. $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) { doWhatYouGotToDo(e.pageX, e.pageY); });